# How to align two equation arrays when combined with lateral braces

Tags: align, braces

I want to have two equation arrays including lateral braces aligned properly.
So far I got

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\overline{z}_k^{[m]} \sim p(z_k| x_{k-1}^{[m]}) & \Leftrightarrow 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  &\overline{r}_k           & \sim\; & \eta_{r}(\mu_{r},\sigma_{r}|r_{k-1},k) \\
  &\overline{\Delta\psi}_k  & \sim\; & \eta_{\Delta\psi}(\mu_{\Delta\psi},\sigma_{\Delta\psi}|k) \\
  &\overline{\Delta h}_k  & \sim\; &\eta_{\Delta h}(\mu_{\Delta h},\sigma_{\Delta h}|k) 
\end{aligned}
\right. \\
\overline{x}_k^{[m]} =  f(\overline{z}_k^{[m]},x_{k-1}^{[m]}) & \Leftrightarrow  
\left\{
\begin{aligned}  
  &\overline{\psi}_k      &=\; &\psi_{k-1} + \overline{\Delta\psi}_k\\  
  &\overline{s}_k        &=\; &s_{k-1} + (\cos(\overline{\psi}_k),\sin(\overline{\psi}_k), 1)^T \cdot
  (\overline{r}_k,\overline{r}_k, \overline{\Delta h}_k)^T
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

This gives me

[image]

The only issue I still have with the result: I'd like to have the tildes and the equal signs aligned across both equation arrays. With my solution this does not seem possible since I use tow aligned environments. With a singular environment I am however incapable of integrating both lateral braces.

Comment: Where do you want the extra gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save yourself quite a few `&` symbols by using `array` instead of `aligned` environments for the material to the right of the two large curly left braces. The `array` preamble, `{@{\:}l@{}l}`, is chosen to get the same spacing around the `\sim` and `=` symbols as you get in an ordinary equation.

To get the spacing of the first column of the second array right, it suffices to insert a single `\makebox[\mathlength][l]{...}`, where `\mathlength` equals the width of $\overline{\Delta\psi}_k$ (the widest element in the first column of the first `array`).

In addition, I would use `\bar` instead of `\overline` in the majority of the cases where `\overline` is used in your example. And, I would use the macro `\mid` instead of the `|` character to get better spacing around the conditioning symbol. Finally, I can't help but suspect that one of the transpose symbols is unneeded; I'll let you be the judge of that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for align environment
\newlength\mathlength
\settowidth{\mathlength}{$\overline{\Delta\psi}_k$}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\bar{z}_k^{[m]} \sim p(z_k\mid x_{k-1}^{[m]}) 
& \Leftrightarrow 
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{\:}l@{}l}
\bar{r}_k 
& {}\sim \eta_{r}(\mu_{r},\sigma_{r} \mid r_{k-1},k) \\[1ex]
\overline{\Delta\psi}_k  
& {}\sim \eta_{\Delta\psi}(\mu_{\Delta\psi},\sigma_{\Delta\psi} \mid k) \\[1ex]
\overline{\Delta h}_k 
& {}\sim \eta_{\Delta h}(\mu_{\Delta h},\sigma_{\Delta h} \mid k) 
\end{array}
\right. \\[1.5ex]
\bar{x}_k^{[m]} =  f(\bar{z}_k^{[m]},x_{k-1}^{[m]}) 
& \Leftrightarrow  
\left\{ % \mkern1.5mu  %% optional, see explanation below
\begin{array}{@{\:}l@{}l}
\makebox[\mathlength][l]{$\bar{\psi}_k$} 
&{}= \psi_{k-1} + \overline{\Delta\psi}_k \\[1ex]  
\bar{s}_k    
&{}= s_{k-1} + (\cos\bar{\psi}_k,\sin\bar{\psi}_k, 1)^T 
\cdot (\bar{r}_k,\bar{r}_k, \overline{\Delta h}_k)^T
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

*Addendum* -- If you're a (typographic) perfectionist, you may want to insert the instruction `\mkern1.5mu` (equivalent to one half of `\thinspace`) between the second pair of `\left\{` and `\begin{array}{...}` instructions, to adjust for the fact that the second left-hand curly brace, which is as tall as two rows, is ever so slightly less wide than the first, which is as tall as three rows.

Comment: This is just perfect, also your addendum is very welcome. Is there a reason for preferring bar vs. overline ?

Comment: @Martin - You're welcome. Speaking (mostly!) for myself, I find that the horizontal bar that's produced by `\overline` looks too heavy or "massive". By contrast, the bar produced by `\bar`, while still perfectly visible, is much less domineering.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to know which is the longest thing needed to be aligned ahead of time.

[image: aligned cases]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{$\displaystyle \overline{\Delta\psi}_k$}

\begin{align}
\overline{z}_k^{[m]} \sim p(z_k| x_{k-1}^{[m]}) & \Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
  \makebox[\mywidth][l]{$\displaystyle \overline{r}_k$} \sim\; \eta_{r}(\mu_{r},\sigma_{r}|r_{k-1},k) \\
  \makebox[\mywidth][l]{$\displaystyle \overline{\Delta\psi}_k$} \sim\; \eta_{\Delta\psi}(\mu_{\Delta\psi},\sigma_{\Delta\psi}|k) \\
  \makebox[\mywidth][l]{$\displaystyle \overline{\Delta h}_k$} \sim\; \eta_{\Delta h}(\mu_{\Delta h},\sigma_{\Delta h}|k) 
\end{cases}
\\
\overline{x}_k^{[m]} =  f(\overline{z}_k^{[m]},x_{k-1}^{[m]}) & \Leftrightarrow  
\begin{cases}  
  \makebox[\mywidth][l]{$\displaystyle \overline{\psi}_k$} =\; \psi_{k-1} + \overline{\Delta\psi}_k\\  
  \makebox[\mywidth][l]{$\displaystyle \overline{s}_k$}    =\; s_{k-1} + (\cos(\overline{\psi}_k),\sin(\overline{\psi}_k), 1)^T \cdot
  (\overline{r}_k,\overline{r}_k, \overline{\Delta h}_k)^T
\end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The whitespace to the left of the `\sim` symbols in the first `aligned` environment is noticeably larger than that to the right of the `\sim` symbols. Is that intentional?

Comment: Not by me.  I left the first equation unchanged from the MWE.  If you like, I can redo it using \cases.

Comment: +1 for figuring out how to use the `cases` environment! Spacing around the `\sim` symbols looks good.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I chose to accept the other one since I personally prefer array over cases but thats just subjective. Anyway: Thanks!